# I'd like to say "We are as flowers" as in 'similar to' for a dorama title. Is 私たちは花のようです acceptable?

Tags: translation, metaphor

So I'm looking to make up some sort of J-dorama and am looking for a proper title. The story is irrelevant, just that the title is supposed to mean that 'we are like flowers', as in 'similar to', but not 'look like' or 'equivalent to'.

Google Translate offers the phrase in the title. It also offers 均しい but I think it's too... rigid? Exact? I'm looking for something more metaphorical.

- Does using よう make it sound more metaphorical than 均しい?
- Does the current phrase in the title acceptable sound like a proper dorama title?
- I'm thinking of removing the です, would that work better as a dorama title?

Comment: I think the title question in and of itself is fine, but asking for additional suggestions is definitely off-topic.

Comment: Fair point. I'll revise my question.

Comment: "Acceptable" to whom?  Does this need to satisfy native Japanese-speakers?

Comment: I mean, I've seen just how long a manga title can be, but I suppose yes, I want it to sound like a real dorama for a native Japanese speaker.

Comment: How about  花のような私たち? "We who are like flowers".